# Flutter package targeting min version

Tags: flutter, dart, packaging

I published a package to pub.dev that uses the Flutter SDK version 1.6.3 which as of today is the beta channel

However the pub analyser uses v1.5.4-hotfix.2 which does not have those API changes just yet, presummably because it is using on the stable channel

When I specified the min version in the pubspec.yml file for flutter it outright failed

```
STDERR:
ERR : The current Flutter SDK version is 1.5.4-hotfix.2.
    | 
    | Because ...... requires Flutter SDK version ^1.6.3, version solving 
failed.
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Is there a way to get the pub website to accept the beta channel builds and not have the package fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this thread https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues/2283 and seems you have to use the stable channel version to publish a package

Answer (score 0):

**try to change sdk 
or 
try to upgrade Flutter Package 
tools>>flutter>>flutter Upgrade**

Comment: Issue is that I built against the beta channel that is a different version than that pub website accepts... which looks like is the stable channel

Comment: in case your lib is not working in ios or android its work only one side than they issue is appears remove last added lib from your pubml